# Get Latest and Popular posts from Linkedin group

Tags: api, linkedin-api

How can I get the Latest and Popular posts from Linkedin Group **Without user authentication**
Wherever I searched it seem to be a requirement for user to sign in.

However how [these guys](http://www.digitalwpc.com/Pages/Home.aspx) managed to get it working without user Logging in?

I understand reasons behind forcing users to log-in in most scenarios. But the above can be seen without logging in on site itself. E.g: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Microsoft-Office-365-3724282

Comment: Have you looked at the developer tools and API from linkedin from http://developer.linkedin.com/?  I am curious whether those were a help.

Comment: Here is some info from the developer part of the linkedin site.  http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-and-social-stream

Comment: Here is the page with links to various implementations of the Linkedin API in various programming languages.  http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools

Comment: Thanks for the last link, I haven't seen this. However that still not resolves the main problem - user required to sign in to see the content through API, that otherwise publicly available (no sign in required) on site.